# How to solve duplicate page in ion-infinite-scroll ionic 4

Tags: ionic4

I am using ionic 4 and I am doing pagination using ion-infinite-scroll. My problem is I always get the duplicate page problem. Can I know how to solve this duplicate problem? Here is my code in home.page.ts:

```
doInfinite(event) {
    this.userService.getData().then(res => {
      event.target.complete();
    });
  }

  loadData(event) {
    console.log('Load more data');

    this.userService.getData().then(res => {
      event.target.complete();
    });
  }
```

Here is home.html

```
<ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="loadData($event)">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content
      loadingSpinner="bubbles"
      loadingText="loading ...">
    </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
  </ion-infinite-scroll>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what your `userService.getData()` looks like.

It doesn't look like you are telling it to start at an offset.

Each time you pull data down, you should assign that list data to some local on-page variable, let's say `dataList`.

Then use `this.dataList.length` as the starting index for your next data request.

So some pseudo-code for how this might work would be:

```
let dataFeed = [];
let startAtRecord = 0;

constructor() {
  this.userService.getData(startAtRecord).then(res => {
    this.dataFeed = res;
    this.startAtRecord = this.dataService.length;
  });
}

loadData(event) {
  // ask for a batch of records, starting at `startAtRecord`
  this.userService.getData(startAtRecord).then(res => {
    // add the new res data to the existing dataFeed
    this.dataFeed = [...this.dataFeed, ...res];
    // keep track of the number of records loaded
    this.startAtRecord = this.dataService.length;
    event.target.complete();
  });
}
```

Do you see what I'm saying? The data service has to load the next page of data so you don't get the same one back, so it needs to track where its starting the list from.

Comment: thank you for your reply, my getData() is get data from API, then I will get my response using array.next

Comment: I've updated my question and added some example code, it won't compile because you are going to need to update your data service to work from a starting offset, but it should give you some idea about how to implement it.